# Fecha SQL mostrar en php hace cuando fue el registro

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Trabajo sobre una tabla de recordatorios y me gustaria poder mostrar hacer cuanto fue creado el registro en mi tabla 

Mi tabla ***tareas*** :

```
id idusuario usuario titulo   Contenido fecha          Estado
1  1         juan    titulo1  aaa qq    17-08-18/12:30 atendido
2  1         juan    titulo2  bbb qq    07-08-18/01:21 pendiente      
3  1         juan    titulo1  ccc qq    05-08-18/11:22 atendiendo
4  2         pepe    titulo2  ddd qq    12-08-18/04:20 pendiente
5  2         pepe    titulo3  eee qq    20-08-18/10:50 canceloado
6  3         alex    titulo4  fff qq    17-08-18/05:59 nadie sabe
```

quiero que en mi tabla donde muestro los compos referentes al usuario juan diga hace cuanto tiempo fue el registro.

Si la fecha del primer registro es : 17-08-18/12:30 y hoy es 17-08-18/12:30 diga ***hace 3m*** y si a pasado un dia poder mostrar el resultado ***hace 1d 3m*** estoy recien creando la base de datos asi que puedo crear cambios sobre la misma si hace falta

Con una consulta como:

```
<?php
$sql_tarea = sqlsrv_query(
$conn, "SELECT tareas 
        FROM periodo where 
                     idusuario=$idsuario
        ORDER BY id DESC");

//$conn contiene mis datos de conecion a my base, 
//y $idsuario es el id del usuario que inicio la secion
 if($c=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                $fecha=$c['fecha'];
                            } 
?>
```

poder hacer que $fecha diga el tiempo transcurrido cuando lo muestre en un echo $fecha

Comment: puedes mostrar un ejemplo del resultado que quieres?

Comment: Hola, Lamak. claro! con mucho gusto edito igual mente mi pregunta pero si la fecha de el primer registro es : 17-08-18/12:30 y hoy es 17-08-18/12:30 diga ***hace 3m*** y si a pasado un dia poder mostrar el resultado ***hace 1d 3m*** estoy recien creando la base de datos asi que puedo crear cambios sobre la misma si hace falta

Comment: Si estas mostrando los datos de la Tabla, puedes crear una vista, o dentro de tu misma consulta agregar un campo extra el cual contendra la diferencia de fechas, en sql hay una funcion para la resta de Fechas/horas (DateDiff), en este caso le restarias ala fecha Actual, la fecha que tiene en tu tabla ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es SQL Server deberia de funcionar algo asi:

```
SELECT tareas , DATEDIFF ( mi, fecha, getdate() )  as 
        FROM periodo where 
                     idusuario=$idsuario
        ORDER BY id DESC
```

El ejemplo solo dira la diferencia de minutos, para algo mas complejo creo que tendrias que meter validaciones.

Igual para mas documentacion puedes ver este link: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: e aceptado la pregunta funciono perfecto! muchas gracias